# NodeJS Native basic authentication

Tags: node.js, url, basic-authentication

Is there a node-native way to parse basic authentication?

Steps would be:

- Find Authentication header
- Parse the encoded value
- Tokenize on the colon and return the user/pass
- Perhaps friendly error handling/messaging on fail

*Not looking for the Connect/Express framework solutions.*

I realize this is pretty trivial to do by hand but it would be nice to have a standard way to achieve this without re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Well, you completely changed the question after I answered. :-) But if you are excluding npm modules apriori, your question is basically a grep in this directory: https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/lib. I think the answer is "not exactly but you can build what you need pretty easily", but just clone that repo and search around.

Answer (score 0):

So HTTP auth has a confusing thing. When you have a URL with credentials like this `https://user:password@example.com', that will parse just fine with`url.parse`:

```
 url.parse('https://user:password@example.com')
{ protocol: 'https:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: 'user:password',
  host: 'example.com',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'example.com',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',
  href: 'https://user:password@example.com/' }
```

Note it's `url.parse(theUrl).auth` not `url.parse(theUrl).query.auth` as you have.

However, that is the URL itself, just that string. If you tell an HTTP library to actually request that URL, the credentials get translated into an HTTP request header, just as the rest of the URL like the host, path, port, etc each gets converted into the details of the request and within the HTTP request header and body itself the full URL is nowhere to be found because it's spread out across both the TCP and HTTP layers.

Which is a long way of saying you need to look in the request headers: `req.headers.authorization`. `url.parse` looks at a simple URL string and what you have on the server is an actual `http.ClientRequest` instance.